# How to insert UITextView in UIImageView and make it to a movable view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to show the contents of a text field in an image view and also need to make it movable in the main view.

Comment: I have an NSString that I would like to draw it's contents to a UIImage but have absolutely NO idea how I would go about doing this. I give it an NSString and returns a UIImage with the text drawn into it and this UIImage i need to drag this UIImage.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right...

For example:
`myImageView` - your UIImageView object,
`textView` - your UITextView object,
`textField` - your UITextField object.

Firs of all - you need to add your textView to the myImageView:

```
CGRect textviewFrame = CGRectZero;
textviewFrame.size = myImageView.frame.size;
textView.frame = textviewFrame;
textView.scrollEnabled = YES; // To enable scroll
textView.editable = NO;
```

Thеn you need to implement UITextField delegate method to update textView text:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    textView.text = textField.text;
}
```

So, that's all you need.